# Python 3: How do I sort both parallel lists?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to be able to sort a parallel list of employee names and their ages, either in ascending or descending order. I can get one list to sort, but I do not have a clue how to get the second list to pair the names with their ages individually. For example I need it to look like this.

```
Phil is 20 years old
Mike is 23 years old
Jenny is 38 years old
Jim is 65 years old
```

But it looks like this.

```
['Jim', 'Jenny', 'Phil', 'Mike'] is [20, 23, 38, 66] years old.
```

Here is my code so far.

```
def get_name():
    employee_name = input("Enter the employee's name: ")
    return employee_name

def get_age():
    while True:
        try:
            employee_age = int(input("Enter the employee's age: "))
            return employee_age
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

def main():
    num_age = []
    string_name = []

    print("This program sorts employee's by age.")

    while True:
        try:
            num_employees = int(input("Enter the number of employee's who are being evaluated: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number.")

    while True:
        for i in range(num_employees):
            num_employees -= 1
            name = get_name()
            string_name += [name]

            age = get_age()
            num_age += [age]

        if num_employees == 0:
            print(str(sorted(string_name)) + " is " + (str(sorted(num_age))) + " years old.")
            break

main()
```

Comment: Why not sort a list of tuples `[(name, age), ...]`? That makes more sense as a structure than *"parallel lists"* anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner to setup the lists:

```
temp = sorted(zip(a,b), key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
```

Formatting:

```
for name, age in temp:
    print(name + " is " + age + " years old")
```

Assuming

```
a = ['Jim', 'Jenny', 'Phil', 'Mike']
b = [20, 23, 38, 66]
```

You may also change reverse=False, or remove it.

Answer (score 3):

One classic approach to this problem is to use Python's built-in zip function to join the lists together and then sort the data. After the sorting has completed you can get back to the original (but sorted) lists:

```
list1 = ['Jim', 'Jenny', 'Phil', 'Mike']
list2 = [65, 38, 20, 23]
list2, list1 = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(list2, list1))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem here is that you have parallel lists.  A better way to hold the data is a single list of "records" that hold all the information about a single employee.  Depending on how much structure you want, you could use `dict`, `tuple`, `namedtuple` or a custom class for your record.  Here's an example with a custom class:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Now you can populate your employees as before:

```
employees = []
for _ in range(num_employees):
    employees.append(Employee(get_name(), get_age())
```

And now you can sort on anything you want.  e.g.:

```
import operator
sorted(employees, key=operator.attrgetter('age'))
```

Comment: FWIW I'd go tuple (or, at most, `namedtuple`) here

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- While it might be overkill _now_, I tend to err on the side of more structure is better.  It's only 4 lines of code ;-) and makes for a more flexible solution if you add more attributes to the employee.  I find that `namedtuple` doesn't really give you much more than a simple class unless you actually want immutability (which might be desirable in this case, but it was too hard to tell).

Answer (score 2):

Try zipping your two lists together to create a list of tuples. Then you can do:

```
sorted([('Jenny', 38),('Jim', 65),('Phil', 20), ('Mike',23)],key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sort_together) has an elegant solution for sorting multiple iterables in parallel.

```
from more_itertools import sort_together

a = ['Jim', 'Jenny', 'Phil', 'Mike']
b = [65, 38, 20, 23]

sort_together([a, b], key_list=[1])
# [('Phil', 'Mike', 'Jenny', 'Jim'), (20, 23, 38, 65)]
```

We selected the second list as the key. To print desired results:

```
for name, age in zip(*sort_together([a, b], key_list=[1])):
    print("{} is {} years old".format(name, age))

# Phil is 20 years old
# Mike is 23 years old
# Jenny is 38 years old
# Jim is 65 years old
```